# How do I reset the useMutation hook of Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am developing a React form that's tied to a GraphQL mutation using the [`useMutation`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/) of [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/). On the server, I perform some validation and in case of errors, I reject the mutation. On the client-side, I use the `error` object to receive the validation errors. My hook looks like this:

```
const [addDrone, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_DRONE)
```

So I unpack the `error` object and present it to the user in a dialog to let him/her know what went wrong. After the user dismisses the dialog, I want to give the user a chance to fix the error so he/she can resubmit the form. This is where things get hairy. I want to clear the `error` object when the user dismisses the dialog, but since this variable comes from the `useMutation` hook there is no way for me to mutate or reset it. It looks like the `useMutation` was designed to be fired once, and not used again.

So my question is, is there a way to "reset" a `useMutation` hook back to it's original state?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE 12/22/2021**: As of version [3.5.0](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#apollo-client-350-2021-11-08) of `@apollo/client` the `useMutation` hook now provides a `reset` method. You can use this method to reset the hook back to its initial state. E.g.:

```
const [addDrone, { error, reset }] = useMutation(ADD_DRONE)
```

Below are some notes from [the official documentation on this method](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#resetting-mutation-status).

> Call reset to reset the mutation's result to its initial state (i.e.,
> before the mutate function was called). You can use this to enable
> users to dismiss mutation result data or errors in the UI.
>
> Calling reset does not remove any cached data returned by the
> mutation's execution. It only affects the state associated with the
> useMutation hook, causing the corresponding component to rerender.

---

Old answer, kept for those who use an older version of `@apollo/client`:

As of 12/26/2020 there's no way to reset a `useMutation`, however there are two feature requests [#157](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/157) [#170](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/170) on the Apollo Feature Request repo asking for one, so this may change in the future.

The easiest way to implement this behavior right now is to drop the `error` variable and use the [`onError`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#usemutation-api) handler instead. This is a callback provided by `useMutation` which uses the same `error` object. You can then wire that to your own stateful variable, which gives you the exact same `error` variable *and* the ability to use `setError` to clear it. See this example below:

```
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)
  const [addDrone] = useMutation(ADD_DRONE, {
    onError: setError,
  })
```

If you're looking to reset the `data` object as well you can introduce another stateful tuple `[data, setData]` and wire the `setData` to the `onCompleted` callback.

Comment: Resetting the mutation result was implemented in `@apollo/client 3.5.x` https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/8859#issuecomment-967332753